# How to I locally test my Dataflow Job with a side input that is refreshed periodically?

Tags: unit-testing, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, emulation, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a Dataflow job in Java that reads input messages from a PubSub topic, takes in a side input that is refreshed every hour, combines information from the side input and PubSub Message, and is written into BigTable.

How can I write a local test (using emulators) to test if the side input is being refreshed periodically?

This is what I plan to do:

1. Create a test Pub/Sub topic and publish test messages to it: In order to test your Dataflow job, you will need to create a test Pub/Sub topic and publish test messages to it. You can use the Pub/Sub emulator to simulate a Pub/Sub environment locally on your machine.
2. Create a test Bigtable instance: You can create a test Bigtable instance using the Google Cloud SDK or by using a test framework like Testcontainers. This will allow you to write test data to Bigtable without affecting your production data.
3. Create a test side input that returns test data: In order to test if your side input is being refreshed periodically, you can create a test side input that returns test data. This test data should be different from the production side input data, so that you can easily tell if the side input has been refreshed.
4. Create a mock function that updates the test side input: You can create a mock function that updates the test side input with new test data. This function can be triggered by a timer or by an external event, such as a test case.
5. Create a test pipeline that uses the test side input and test Pub/Sub topic: You can create a test pipeline that uses the test side input and test Pub/Sub topic, and writes test data to the test Bigtable instance.
6. Run the test pipeline and verify the output: You can run the test pipeline and verify the output to ensure that the test data is being written to Bigtable correctly. You can also verify that the test side input is being refreshed periodically by checking the test data that is being written to Bigtable

However, is there a more straightforward way to write this test?

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT generated a detailed implementation steps!!!. Yes, this is how you do it locally - is there any specific detail you are looking for?

Comment: I'm specifically using the PeriodicImpulse method to cause the periodic refresh of side input (and not manually triggered), so I was wondering how it could be tested.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice writeup on the Apache Beam blog called [Testing Unbounded Pipelines in Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/test-stream/) that should be helpful for your use case here.

In particular, the Java SDK includes a `TestStream` class that allows you to specify records to be injected as specific time offsets. The simplest use case documented in the blog post is:

```java
TestStream<GameActionInfo> createEvents = TestStream.create(AvroCoder.of(GameActionInfo.class))
    .addElements(new GameActionInfo("sky", "blue", 12, new Instant(0L)),
                 new GameActionInfo("navy", "blue", 3, new Instant(0L)),
                 new GameActionInfo("navy", "blue", 3, new Instant(0L).plus(Duration.standardMinutes(3))))
    // Move the watermark past the end the end of the window
    .advanceWatermarkTo(new Instant(0L).plus(TEAM_WINDOW_DURATION)
                                       .plus(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
    .advanceWatermarkToInfinity();

PCollection<KV<String, Integer>> teamScores = p.apply(createEvents)
    .apply(new CalculateTeamScores(TEAM_WINDOW_DURATION, ALLOWED_LATENESS));
```

To test that the side input is being triggered correctly, I expect you'll need to provide a fake that somehow responds to the current processing time in the pipeline. I'm not aware of a way to use `TestStream` to indicate that a batch source used as a side input should be updated at a particular time.